# How to tag EC2 instance when it does not match the whitelisted AMI ID and tag it as "not approved"

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How to tag a new instance when it is in runstate to stopstate, this lambda function is to match the whitelisted AMI ID (AMI ID's are in notepad in S3), if the Instance is not matching the approved AMI ID, then the ec2 will be forced to stop and tag it as "not approved" using Python 3.

```
import boto3
import botocore
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    account = event['account']
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    bucketname = 'amivalidation-demo'
    filename = 'ami-s3.csv'
    fileObj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=filename)
    file_content = fileObj["Body"].read().decode('utf-8')
    ec2_client = get_client('ec2',account)
    response = event['detail']['responseElements']['instancesSet']
    for res in response['items']:
        instance = res['instanceId']
        image = res['imageId']
        if image in file_content:
            #image in whitelist
            pass
        else:
            #image not in whitelist, kill it!
            ec2_client.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[instance],Force=True)
    return
```

Comment: You appear to have written an AWS Lambda function that is receiving information via an `event` record. What event would be triggering this Lambda function?  Are you responding to a particular Amazon CloudWatch Event similar to [How to Automatically Tag Amazon EC2 Resources in Response to API Events | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-automatically-tag-amazon-ec2-resources-in-response-to-api-events/)? Please edit your question to add these details.

Comment: Does your code work? Are you experiencing any errors? You ask "how to shutdown", but there is already a `stop_instances()` call in your code. What is your actual question?

Comment: Hi John, here i rephrased the question:

How to tag a new instance when it is in runstate to stopstate, this lambda function is to match the whitelisted AMI ID (AMI ID's are in notepad in S3), if the Instance is not matching the approved AMI ID, then the ec2 will be forced to stop and tag it as "not approved" using Python 3.

Comment: Hi John, here i rephrased the question:
Yes i am running an Lambda function that receives the events from the CloudWatch, The events are like when somebody spins the new EC2 it should check the whitelisted AMI's and take the necessary action like if it matches "no action" and it it dose not match its will "stop the Instance and tag as non approved".

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying how your code is being used. So, could you please tell us **what is your question?** Does your code not work? What is the problem you are experiencing? Are you simply asking which API call to make to add a tag? (It would be `create_tags()`)

Comment: Code is working fine need to know how to tag the instance after it shutdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`create_tags()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_tags):

```py
response = ec2_client.create_tags(
    Resources=['instance-id'],
    Tags=[
        {
            'Key': 'string',
            'Value': 'string'
        },
    ]
)
```